# How do you change the colour of each category within a highcharts column chart?

Tags: highcharts

I have have a column chart which has a number of categories, each with a single data point (e.g. [like this one](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/column-rotated-labels)). Is it possible to change the colour of the bar for each category? i.e. so each bar would have its own unique colour rather than all being blue?

Answer (score 116, accepted):

You can also set the color individually for each point/bar if you change the data array to be configuration objects instead of numbers.

```
data: [
      {y: 34.4, color: 'red'},     // this point is red
      21.8,                        // default blue
      {y: 20.1, color: '#aaff99'}, // this will be greenish
      20]                          // default blue
```

[Example on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dapYa/)

[image]

Comment: The correct answer should be from @antonversal ! Automatic ``{plotOptions: {column: {colorByPoint: true}}}`` magic!

Answer (score 70):

Also you can set option:

```
  {plotOptions: {column: {colorByPoint: true}}}
```

for more information read [docs](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.column.colorByPoint)

Comment: This should be the correct answer. It is impractical to manually set the colour of each bar in the series.

Answer (score 33):

Add which colors you want to `colors` and then set `colorByPoint` to `true`.

```
colors: [
'#4572A7', 
'#AA4643', 
'#89A54E', 
'#80699B', 
'#3D96AE', 
'#DB843D', 
'#92A8CD', 
'#A47D7C', 
'#B5CA92'
],

plotOptions: {
    column: {
        colorByPoint: true
    }
}
```

[**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/plotoptions/column-colorbypoint-true/)

Reference:

- http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#colors
- http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.column.colorByPoint

Answer (score 17):

Yes, here is an example in jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bfQeJ/

```
Highcharts.setOptions({
    colors: ['#058DC7', '#50B432', '#ED561B', '#DDDF00', '#24CBE5', '#64E572', '#FF9655', '#FFF263', '#6AF9C4']
});
```

The example is a pie chart but you can just fill the series with all the colors to your heart's content =)

Comment: hey i've tried to use the code above but my whole graph changes to the first colo #058DC7 instead without any color variation . Is there any way to set the color variation to automatic ?

Comment: You could have at least used a column chart for the demo.

Comment: It wont' work because all the data points are in one series, and those colours are for colouring in series...

Answer (score 10):

You can add colors array in high chart graph for changing the color of graph. You can re-arrange these colors and you can also specify your own colors.

```
$('#container').highcharts({
colors: ['#2f7ed8','#910000','#8bbc21','#1aadce'],
chart: {
type: 'column'
},
title: {
text: 'Stacked column chart'
},
```

Answer (score 4):

Like mentioned by antonversal, reading the colors and using the colors option when creating the chart object works.

```
var chart3 = new Highcharts.Chart({colors: ['#458006', '#B0D18C']});
```

Answer (score 2):

just put chart

```
$('#container').highcharts({
colors: ['#31BFA2'], // change color here
chart: {
        type: 'column'
}, .... Continue chart
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add this...or you can change the colors as per your demand.

```
Highcharts.setOptions({
        colors: ['#811010', '#50B432', '#ED561B', '#DDDF00', '#24CBE5', '#64E572', '#FF9655', '#FFF263', '#6AF9C4'],
        plotOptions: {
            column: {
                colorByPoint: true
            }
        }

    });
```

Answer (score 1):

add properties:

```
 colors: ['Red', 'Bule', 'Yellow']
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me. Its tedious to set all the colour options for a series, especially if it's dynamic

```
plotOptions: {
  column: {
   colorByPoint: true
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
{plotOptions: {bar: {colorByPoint: true}}}
```