# Highcharts Onload default select a bar

Tags: asp.net, highcharts

I am creating a `highchart` that should have a default bar selected (diff color) on load of the `highchart`. How is this possible on `Asp.net`??

Comment: Yes its possible, see this answer on individual colored bars: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7414287/how-do-you-change-the-colour-of-each-category-within-a-highcharts-column-chart/7415737#7415737

Answer (score 0):

You could also try out the C# wrapper for the Javascript API available at http://highcharts.codeplex.com

It proveds exhaustive support for the original Javascript API in C#, and also comes with a default implementation for an Ajax data source with a single line of code.