# Coloured scatter-plots with javascript

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I need a scatterplot like this: http://www.highcharts.com/demo/scatter but, instead of having one color for each serie (male and female, in the example), I need to select the color for each element. Following the example, each person would be coloured with a different level of gray, depending on their age.

As far as I know, Highcharts allow you to select the color of the elements, but it only affects the element pop-up information when you're using scatterplot.

Any other library to do scatterplots? Any way to do it with Highcharts?

Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps [FLOT](http://www.flotcharts.org/)

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7414287/how-do-you-change-the-colour-of-each-category-within-a-highcharts-column-chart

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be able to do this inside Hightcharts using the `color` property inside the `data` array.

You can see the documentation [here](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#series.data), and there is also an [example](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/point/color/) for this.

You could try preprocessing your `data` and transform it appending the `color` information to the array.

Comment: +1 pointing the OP to documentation in his chosen chart tool and finding an example

Comment: Right, but the data.color property does not work as I need with scatterplots. See http://jsfiddle.net/yrAzx/ , where I've just changed 'column' by 'scatter' in the Javascript. As you can see, the circle is still blue, it's the pop-up info what changes the color.

Comment: That's because in the scatter case, what you are seeing is actually the marker!! Check this [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jbalsas/yrAzx/2/). You can see it working there :)

Comment: Happy to help! Please, accept the answer if that was all you needed

Answer (score 0):

I've used [AMCharts](http://www.amcharts.com/) in a few javascript projects, they include a scatter chart and are quick and very easy to implement.

They have a free version if you are happy with their name in the corner of your chart canvas.

To set the colour of a specific point you can set the `color` property of a `GraphDataItem` - as in this documentation http://www.amcharts.com/docs/v.2/javascript_reference/graphdataitem