# How can I get every bar in different colour using Highchart?

Tags: highcharts

The Highchart graph code is shown below I want every bar label color is different. Currently, I'm getting the same color in bar

```
 Highcharts.chart('container', {
            chart: {
                type: 'column',
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Popular '
            },
            credits:{
                enabled:false
            },
            xAxis: {
                max: 20,
                type: 'category',
                style:{
                    fontSize: '12px'
                }
            },
            yAxis: {
                min: 0,
                allowDecimals:false,
                title: {
                    text: 'Number of applications',
                    style:{
                       fontSize: '12px'
                    }
                },
                gridLineWidth:0,
                minorGridLineWidth: 0,
                tickLength: 5,
                tickWidth: 1,
                tickPosition: 'inside',
                lineWidth:1
            },
            scrollbar: {
                enabled: true
            },
            legend: {
                enabled: false
            },

            tooltip: {
                pointFormat: 'hi'
            },
            series: [{
                name: Stats',
                data: data,
                color:'#2ecc71',
                pointWidth: 25,
            }],
```

Data format is :
[
    [
        "Qualcom",
        17
    ],
    [
        "The ram",
        12
    ],
    [
        "Aoperty",
        8
    ],
    [
        "Ob.",
        8
    ],
    [
        "Sugh",
        8
    ],
]

The output is shown in the picture I want every bar is in a different color can[image] you help me?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you change the colour of each category within a highcharts column chart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7414287/how-do-you-change-the-colour-of-each-category-within-a-highcharts-column-chart)

Comment: @Cassio, But my data format is different from this.     data: [
      [
        "Qualcom",
        17
      ],
      [
        "The ram",
        12
      ],
      [
        "Aoperty",
        8
      ],
      [
        "Ob.",
        8
      ],
      [
        "Sugh",
        8
      ]
    ]. In this format my x-axis value is qualcom, sugh etc and y-axis value is count which is 8 or 4 etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Referring to comments you can set a specific color to a single point by adding a color property programmatically to its object like that:

```
  series: [{
    data: [
      ["Qualcom", 17],
      {
        name: "The ram",
        y: 12,
        color: 'red'
      },
      ["Aoperty", 8],
      ["Ob.", 8],
      ["Sugh", 8]
    ],
    color: '#2ecc71'
  }]
```

**API reference:**

- https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.column.data.color

**Demo:**

- https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/craqy1sv/1/

---

If you want to add a specific color to a point when a condition is matched you can loop through each series point in chart load event and update a matched point:

```
  chart: {
    type: 'column',
    events: {
        load: function() {
        var chart = this,
            series = chart.series[0];

        series.points.forEach(function(point) {
          if (point.name === 'The ram') {
            point.update({
                color: 'red'
            })
          }
        });
      }
    }
  }
```

**API reference:**

- https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.events.load
- https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Point#update

**Demo:**

- https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/jmuoevz1/

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `colorByPoint :true` to use different colors like that

```
  series: [{
    name: 'Stats',
    data: [
      [
        "Qualcom",
        17
      ],
      [
        "The ram",
        12
      ],
      [
        "Aoperty",
        8
      ],
      [
        "Ob.",
        8
      ],
      [
        "Sugh",
        8
      ]
    ],
    colorByPoint: true,
    pointWidth: 25,
  }]
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1xhL3r6j/)

Comment: @Corre972 I want specific color in a single bar or may be in more than one bar here is the small data given bye me but I have large set of data like size of aaray is 100 or greater.

Comment: Suppose if name is The Ram then I want to change the bar color in red and left all is in same color

Comment: @vikash, as long as the colors to used are defined you can do what ever you want [Documentation](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/colors).

Comment: @Corre972, But how can I assign a color to the bar if my condition is matched? Thanks