# How to change bar chart colors when is weekend?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I want to change de color of the bar columns on my chart when the xaxis value is a weekend day.

Here is a sample of my data:

```
[
  [
    1564034400000,
    291681
  ],
  [
    1564120800000,
    1533580
  ],
  [
    1564207200000,
    985398
  ],
  [
    1564293600000,
    451679
  ],
  [
    1564380000000,
    1051938459
  ],
  [
    1564466400000,
    1486601
  ],
  [
    1564552800000,
    1712150
  ],
  [
    1564639200000,
    1719820
  ],
  [
    1564725600000,
    2142532
  ],
  [
    1564812000000,
    1332015
  ]
]
```

i've tried this ():

```
data.forEach(x => {              
            ndata.push([x.date, x.eApar]);    
            if(x.date.getDay()==0 || x.date.getDay()==6){
              bcolor="orange"
            }
            else
            {
              bcolor="";
            }
        });
```

and then on the chart building i have this:

```
plotOptions: {
              series: {
                color: bcolor
              },
series: [{
          data: ndata,
          type: 'column',
        }],
```

But it change the color of all the columns.

I hope you can help me, thanks!

Comment: maybe those answers can be useful: https://stackoverflow.com/q/7737409/8732818

Comment: Can you post an online example of your code?]

Comment: Also, can you post your data array

Comment: Calvin Nunes: No. :/ 'Cause that answers are for when i'm building the chart using series.data.push, and i'm not using that. I just give the data like an array that i receive from a Json. And the others answers are sequence or give the data manueally. Hope you understand me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try setting your data on two different series (with missing values on the days according to weekdays or weekend days), then defining color for each serie like here:

```
series: [
{
    name: 'weekend',
    color: '#ffffff',
    data: [null, null, null, null, null, value, value]
}
];
 series: [
{
    name: 'weekdays',
    color: '#f20303',
    data: [value, value, value, value, value, null, null]
}
];
```

EDIT:
There is a better yet solution in the answer to this very problem given by @eolsson here: [How do you change the colour of each category within a highcharts column chart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7414287/how-do-you-change-the-colour-of-each-category-within-a-highcharts-column-chart). Give the different points a color attribute like this:

```
  data: [
  {y: 34.4, color: 'red'},     // this point is red
  21.8,                        // default blue
  {y: 20.1, color: '#aaff99'}, // this will be greenish
  20]
```