# Highcharts column chart: create color groups

Tags: javascript, html, highcharts

I took the code from highcharts demo. The columns are in the color. I would like to modify colors, smt. like to assign blue to some of them and the rest in orange. I post here the code and the link in jsfiddle below. Here is the code:

html:

```
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script

<figure class="highcharts-figure">
    <div id="container"></div>
    <p class="highcharts-description">
        Chart showing ...
    </p>
</figure>
```

js:

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        type: 'column'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'World\'s largest cities per 2017'
    },
    subtitle: {
        text: 'Source: <a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_cities_proper_by_population">Wikipedia</a>'
    },
    xAxis: {
        type: 'category',
        labels: {
            rotation: -45,
            style: {
                fontSize: '10px',
                fontFamily: 'Verdana, sans-serif'
            }
        }
    },
    yAxis: {
        min: 0,
        title: {
            text: 'Population (millions)'
        }
    },
    legend: {
        enabled: false
    },
    tooltip: {
        pointFormat: 'Population in 2017: <b>{point.y:.1f} millions</b>'
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'Population',
        data: [
        ['Shanghai', 24.2],
        ['Beijing', 20.8],
        ['Karachi', 14.9],
        ['Shenzhen', 13.7],
        ['Guangzhou', 13.1],
        ['Istanbul', 19.7],
        ['Mumbai', 12.4],
        ['Moscow', 14.2],
        ['São Paulo', 12.0],
        ['Delhi', 18.7],
        ['Kinshasa', 15.5]
        ],
        dataLabels: {
        enabled: true,
        rotation: -90,
        color: '#FFFFFF',
        align: 'right',
        format: '{point.y:.1f}', // one decimal
        y: 10, // 10 pixels down from the top
        style: {
            fontSize: '10px',
            fontFamily: 'Verdana, sans-serif'
        }
    }
    }]
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/dcmpg1z2/1/

I would like to see "Delhi" and "Kinshasa" in orange color. And the rest in different color. How can I do it?

Comment: This should lead you in the right direction https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7414287/how-do-you-change-the-colour-of-each-category-within-a-highcharts-column-chart

Comment: @Aaron, perfect, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want each category to take different color, you should set  `colorByPoint` to `true`
and explicitly specify the colors for the ones you want to set by passing an object with the `name`, `y` and the `color` property.

here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/trba6uef/)

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/gyk0njmu/ this one is correct, I edited your code, please edit yours then I will accept it.

Comment: all were correct, I just added colors manually, there is a color list.